# Can't get the javascript to work in HTML form in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, jsfiddle

I am putting together an html form where i can add users to an email distribution list. I am trying to mock this up on jfiddle but for some reason the javascript is not working. When i just save the following code in an html page and try it in a browser it works ok. My question is what is that i am doing wrong in jsfiddle and the javascript function doesn't work. Thanks!

The jsfiddle that is not working is here: [MyFiddleExample](https://jsfiddle.net/snicolaou/cm920qs6/45/)

[image: My Form]

```js
function onAddClicked() {
  var userList = document.getElementById("UserList");
  var distributionList = document.getElementById("DistributionList");

  var newMember = document.createElement('option');
  newMember.value = userList.options[userList.selectedIndex].value;
  newMember.innerHTML = userList.options[userList.selectedIndex].text;

  distributionList.appendChild(newMember);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="UserList">Available Users:</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="UserList" size=10 id="UserList">
        <option value="UserA">User A</option>
        <option value="UserB">User B</option>
        <option value="UserC">User C</option>
        <option value="UserD">User D</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" onclick="onAddClicked()" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="margin-top:33px">Add &gt;&gt;</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" style="margin-top:33px">&lt;&lt; Remove</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="DistributionList">Distribution List Members:</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="DistributionList" size=10 id="DistributionList">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If it works in a browser but not in JSFiddle, it's either a copy/paste error or a bug in JSFiddle.

Comment: You use jquery in jsfidle, try with this code and use jquery : $('.btn-success').click(function() {
    if(val != undefined) {
        var val = $("select#UserList option:checked").val();
        $("select#DistributionList").append($('<option>', {
          value: val,
          text: val
        }));
     }
});

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Shim-Sao, i will keep that in mind, but the purpose of the question was to understand why the jsfiddle wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specific to JSFiddle. You need to change the LOAD TYPE to No wrap - bottom of `<body>`.

When using on DOM load, the function won't become global one, so you can't invoke it directy from HTML. If it is global - like when using no-wrap - it works.